# Webpack multiple configuration fails

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm trying to use two configurations with webpack, but it fails in any way that I try, I allways get this message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

In the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/#exporting-multiple-configurations), it says that it is supported, even with an array of functions:

> Instead of exporting a single configuration object/function, you may export multiple configurations (multiple functions are supported since webpack 3.1.0). When running webpack, all configurations are built.

I'm using `webpack@4.31.0` and `webpack-cli@3.3.2`.

This is the error:

```
$ webpack --info-verbosity verbose
C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:281
                                        compiler.hooks.beforeRun.tap("WebpackInfo", compilation => {
                                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined
    at processOptions (C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:281:31)
    at yargs.parse (C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:373:3)
    at Object.parse (C:\Users\...\node_modules\yargs\yargs.js:567:18)
    at C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\...\node_modules\webpack-cli\bin\cli.js:375:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    ...
```

And this is my code ([full code here](https://gist.github.com/lmcarreiro/101f4363281472ed6c6e16ac14975f0f)):

```
// @ts-check
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig];                    // Error: Array of functions that returns the object fails
//module.exports = env => [clientConfig(env), serverConfig(env)]; // Error: Function that return an array of objects fails
//module.exports = [clientConfig(), serverConfig()];              // Error: Array of objects fails
//module.exports = clientConfig; // OK: The first function alone works
//module.exports = serverConfig; // OK: The other function alone works


function serverConfig(env) {
  return {
    target: 'node',
    // ...
  };
}


function clientConfig(env) {
  return {
    target: 'web',
    //...
  };
}
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/lmcarreiro/101f4363281472ed6c6e16ac14975f0f).

### Update:

Related issue: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/570#issuecomment-499093581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use another version of webpack

> "webpack": "4.20.2"

I have seen that there are some people report that that have this issue when they using webpack 4.30 and above

Also try to use HtmlWebPackPlugin that have version above "4.0.0-alpha"

Then delete your package-lock.json and node_modules then run npm i again

Update:

Make sure to run `--watch` in your command line

Comment: Same error, using `webpack@4.20.2` and `html-webpack-plugin@4.0.0-beta.5`, deleted `node_modules` and `yarn.lock` and ran `yarn install` again. I tried all 3 ways (array of function, function returning an array of objects, and array of objects), none of them worked.

Comment: The error was related with the way that I am calling the webpack, with `--info-verbosity verbose`. More details here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/570#issuecomment-499093581

Comment: I was using `--info-verbosity verbose` and setting `watch: true` in the config. Just put `--watch` in the command line and it worked. Thanks for trying to help, you didn't have enough info. If you want to change the answer, I will accept it.